# DOM elements return rubbish

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

was trying to print the length of $("p") but it only returned 1 or 0 (length should be 20+ in length) so i did this to try to see what the "p" element was returning.

[image]

Comment: its not an error, `text()` is a function and not a variable. You need `.innerHTML`

Comment: `text()` is a function and thus requires parentheses.

Comment: 1. you should put the relevant code in the question 2. `.text` is a function. You need to call `.text()` to get the content

Comment: Here's a link to the `.text()` function's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but Atom is a good editor to use if you don't want to buy Sublime.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] in the future.

Comment: @jdgregson thank you, sublime good for now but might look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using jQuery. In this case $(elem).text is a function, calling it without the brackets '()' will cause it to print out the function rather than call it.

Try

```
$("p").text()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, had been getting errors with different results but same concepts. Broadened my understanding of jquery/html/javascript.